# saving word file in a particular location

Tags: java, swing, file, path, jfilechooser

I want to save my file in user selected location in java swing application. I am generating word file dynamically. Moreover When I am putting like this

```
FileWriter _file = new FileWriter("C:/Calender"+.doc", true);
```

the file is getting generated in c:/ drive directly in the name of Calender.doc.

However If i am passing path through

```
jfilechooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()
```

returning the value `"C:\Users\Shorav\Desktop"` is not saving any file in this location.

Please help; how to save the file.

Code is

```
chooser = new JFileChooser();
        chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
        chooser.setDialogTitle("Select location to save the file");
        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
        chooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

        if (chooser.showOpenDialog(null) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
//          System.out.println("getCurrentDirectory(): "+ chooser.getCurrentDirectory());
//          System.out.println("getSelectedFile() : "+ chooser.getSelectedFile());
            System.out.println("Absolute Path : " +chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
        } else {
            System.out.println("No Selection ");
        }
```

This will ask from User for desired location  to save the file.

Then this is returning the path by `C:\Users\Shorav\Desktop`. I want to generate the word file  on this location through the following

```
 FileWriter _file = new FileWriter("C:/Calender"+.doc", true);
```

This is returning word file.

Comment: `"C:\Users\Shorav\Desktop"` you must escape those backslashes.

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: I did not get it?? please explain.

Comment: Why not use the File returned from the `getSelectedFile() method and pass it into your FileWriter rather than the path String?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, I got it.

Answer (score 2):

You will get location of a folder user selected with `jfilechooser.getSelectedFile`. Use it to construct a `File` object and pass it to `FileWriter`.

```
File selectedFile = jfilechooser.getSelectedFile();
FileWriter _file = new FileWriter(new File(selectedFile, "Calender.doc"), true);
```